# How to set authentication to sign in with Google AngularFire using Angular 2+

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I cannot find how to Authenticate using Google after over 3 hours of Googling.
I tried other "signinwith..." options but am getting no where. Below is the code.

```
  constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, 
              public af: AngularFireDatabase)                 {
    this.items = af.list('/messages', {
      query: {
        limitToLast: 50
      }
    });
    this.user = this.afAuth.authState;
  }
  login() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signInAnonymously(); //signIn??????
  }
```

Angular is great but it changes so often and documentation, tutorials and examples are quickly out of date. Thank you for looking.

Answer (score 1):

I found what I was looking for, it is unbelievable what a cup of coffee can do.

https://angularfirebase.com/snippets/angularfire2-version-4-authentication-service/

Thank you